# MVC 4 openauth - custom datastore

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, azure, oauth

I'm trying to use the built-in OpenAuth setup in ASP.NET MVC 4 - and I feel like I must be missing something.

Without realising it, it appears the default role provider sneakily creates & utilizes a local SQL membership database.

This feels like an absolutely insane decision - as it would be my opinion that any website that requires user-login functionality would probably have it's own database configuration.

My Question - **Is there are public interface or something I can override/DI to provide a different storage mechanism?**

I wish to use Azure table storage for my user accounts - and it would appear that it's impossible to unpick this implementation from the `WebSecurity` class - which requires a SQL database to be configured.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the DataStore in Web.config by editing the connection string.